# Different output in HANA and Data pulled using Python

Tags: python, sql, ipython, hana

I am running a query in HANA studio (just like pgadmin for postgres). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

If you see I get the right data pulled when running the query inside HANA studio.

Now when I connect my jupyter notebook with HANA using pyhdb and run the same query I get some NAN which I am not sure why is happening?

[image]

Any suggestion why is this happening?

Comment: You don't enforce any order in your queries, therefore they can return different data (unless your table only contains 5 rows).

Comment: No. There is no null values in the table. Even if I enforce order it is putting some values to null in python. Something is going wrong with python pull